# Parsing a Json array in angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, json, html

I have a json data of the formate

```
 $scope.jsondata = [{filename:"/home/username/textfiles/0101907.txt"},{filename:"/home/username/textfiles/0124757.txt"},{filename:"/home/username/textfiles/0747332.txt"} ... ];
```

And my HTML code is :

```
<li ng-repeat="x in jsondata">
   {{x.filename}}                     
</li>
```

When i run the above code I am getting full path. like "**/home/username/textfiles/0101907.txt**". I just want file name like "**0101907.txt**", instead of full path. Can any one help me in parsing the JSON array. Split the path and get only the file name. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to split the string using "/" and then pop the file name from the array.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in jsondata">
   {{x.filename.split("/").pop()}}                     
</li>
```

Comment: HI bhuvan, what if the json format is like this : `$scope.jsondata = [{"key":"filename","value":"/home/username/textfile/0101907.txt"},{"key":"filename","value":"/home/username/textfile/0124757.txt"}];`

Comment: in a key and value pair.

Comment: when you do ng-repeat, you get each key-value pairs. Hence you could just access the value and ignore the key. <li ng-repeat="x in jsondata">
   {{x.value.split("/").pop()}}                     
</li>

Answer (score 1):

You can update it via `regex`. Create a controller method like `getFileName` & use it in html like below

```
function getFileName(path) {
   return path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
}
```

**HTML**

Use it like

```
<li ng-repeat="x in jsondata">
   {{getFileName(x.filename)}}                     
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Agam, what if the json format is like this : $scope.jsondata = [{"key":"filename","value":"/home/username/textfile/0101907.‌​txt"},{"key":"filena‌​me","value":"/home/u‌​sername/textfile/012‌​4757.txt"}];

Comment: @naik3 In that case, you need to pass the `value` to the `getFileName` method

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using [**`.lastIndexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf). Like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in jsondata">
   {{x.filename.substr(x.filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1}}                     
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve

```
<li ng-repeat="x in jsondata">
{{x.filename.split("/").reverse()[0]}}
</li>
```